# Running Sphinx html make gets stuck after reading sources

Tags: python, pycharm, python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx for the first time to get documentation from docstrings in my code. I am currently using pycharm to run a sphinx task but I did not have luck with the command line either. The problem is that the process gets struck without returning any error:

```
Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
```

Then nothing.

I tried to follow the Sphinx documentation and guides available online, but maybe I got something wrong. These is my index.rst file:

```
Welcome to Mycode's documentation!
===================================

Contents:

.. automodule:: mycode
   :members:

___________________________________

**Sub-Modules:  **

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   mycode.TerminalColors


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

And this is my conf.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../docs'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../scripts'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../source'))
print(sys.path)

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinxcontrib.napoleon'
]

# Napoleon settings
napoleon_google_docstring = True
napoleon_numpy_docstring = True
napoleon_include_private_with_doc = False
napoleon_include_special_with_doc = True
napoleon_use_admonition_for_examples = False
napoleon_use_admonition_for_notes = False
napoleon_use_admonition_for_references = False
napoleon_use_ivar = False
napoleon_use_param = True
napoleon_use_rtype = True

autodoc_member_order = 'groupwise'

templates_path = ['.templates']

source_suffix = '.rst'

master_doc = 'index'

project = u'Mycode'
copyright = u'2016, Me'
version = '1.0'
release = '1.0'
exclude_patterns = []
pygments_style = 'sphinx'

html_theme = 'default'
html_static_path = ['.static']
htmlhelp_basename = 'Mycodedoc'

latex_elements = {}
latex_documents = [
  ('index', 'Mycode.tex', u'Mycode Documentation',
   u'me', 'manual'),
]

man_pages = [
    ('index', 'mycode', u'mycode Documentation',
     [u'me'], 1)
]

texinfo_documents = [
  ('index', 'Mycode', u'Mycode Documentation',
   u'me', 'Mycode', 'One line description of project.',
   'Miscellaneous'),
]
```

Finally, this is my project structure:

```
-mycode
   -scripts
      -mycode.py
   -docs(output folder)
      -index.html
      -...
   -build
   -source
       -conf.py
       -index.rst
```

Any help will be very appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It appears that any ***wait-like function*** in a module will cause Sphinx to hang when importing it if it is executed at import time. I was using ROS and **rospy.wait_for_service** was causing the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a wait-like function is? Are you suggesting if something like `sleep()` is found in a module, it will hang? Also how did you solve it? Move the offending line to a `__main__` def or something?

Comment: Hi, sure. 4 years passed and I don't remember if the same would happen with python `sleep()`, but I don't think so. For context, ROS is a framework for robotics that allows several process to cooperate in a service/client or publish/subscribe way. My explanation back then was that since Sphinx imports the documented modules and all module-level code is executed, if you used a ROS function which waits for a response or signal from another ROS process, it would get struck indefinitely because such processes are not running. Moving the offending line inside a function fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. The issue I faced had a similar effect I was seeing. I filed a ticket against sphinx and we worked together to solve it, so it's no longer an issue for myself either. Much obliged!